# Flash a3 - stopping at a cue point

Tags: actionscript-3, streaming, points, flv, cue-points

I have an flv vid and set the cue point dynamically

```
vid.addASCuePoint(1, "cuePoint1");
```

How ever it does not always stop in the same place. How can I be more exact? I take this is due to buffering and a few other factors?

```
import fl.video.*;
//etc etc 
vid.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.READY, flvPlayback_ready);
vid.addEventListener(MetadataEvent.CUE_POINT, flvPlayback_cuePoint);

function flvPlayback_ready(evt:fl.video.VideoEvent):void {
vid.addASCuePoint(1, "cuePoint1");
vid.play();
}


function flvPlayback_cuePoint(evt:MetadataEvent):void {
    vid.pause();
    trace("CUE POINT!!!");
    trace("\t", "name:", evt.info.name); // name: cuePoint1
   trace("\t", "time:", evt.info.time); // time: 1
   trace("\t", "type:", evt.info.type); // type: actionscript
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuepoints can be added to a video in two ways:
1) encoded into the actual video
2) added via actionscript

I don't have any links to the appropriate documentation, but I've dealt with this problem before.   The stuff I read says that adding cuepoints via actionscript will not be as accurate as encoding them onto the video.  ...and your code indicates that this is how you are adding them...

I wish I had better news for you, but the only way I am aware of to get more accuracy is to add the keypoints during encoding.

Comment: In the end I just spit the video.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to the number of keyframes that the flv was encoded with (I think the number is 1 per 30 frames by default when encoding with MediaEncoder).

Try re-encoding the flv and set the Key Frame Distance to something smaller (or even embed the keyframe using Media Encoder rather than adding it via ActionScript).